# How to create request with parameters with webflux Webclient?

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux

At backend side I have REST controller with POST method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Integer save(@RequestParam String name) {
   //do save
   return 0;
}
```

How can I create request using [WebClient](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#webflux-client) with request parameter?

```
WebClient.create(url).post()
    .uri("/save")
    //?
    .exchange()
    .block()
    .bodyToMono(Integer.class)
    .block();
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There are many encoding challenges when it comes to creating URIs. For more flexibility while still being right on the encoding part, `WebClient` provides a builder-based variant for the URI:

```
WebClient.create().get()
    .uri(builder -> builder.scheme("http")
                    .host("example.org").path("save")
                    .queryParam("name", "spring-framework")
                    .build())
    .retrieve()
    .bodyToMono(String.class);
```

Comment: Yes, same applies to POST requests

Answer (score 10):

From: https://www.callicoder.com/spring-5-reactive-webclient-webtestclient-examples/

In configuration class you can define the host:

```
@Bean(name = "providerWebClient")
WebClient providerWebClient(@Value("${external-rest.provider.base-url}") String providerBaseUrl) {
return WebClient.builder().baseUrl(providerBaseUrl)
    .clientConnector(clientConnector()).build();
}
```

Then you can use the WebClient instace:

```
@Qualifier("providerWebClient")
private final WebClient webClient;

webClient.get()
        .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder.path("/provider/repos")
                .queryParam("sort", "updated")
                .queryParam("direction", "desc")
                .build())
        .header("Authorization", "Basic " + Base64Utils
                .encodeToString((username + ":" + token).getBytes(UTF_8)))
        .retrieve()
        .bodyToFlux(GithubRepo.class);
```

Comment: What about the host? Where have you specified it?

Comment: @MikayilAbdullayev I've just edited my answer to add that part of the configuration.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming that you already created your *WebClient* instance and configured it with ***baseUrl***.

### URI Path Component

```
this.webClient.get()
      .uri("/products")
      .retrieve();
```

result: ***/products***

```
this.webClient.get()
      .uri(uriBuilder - > uriBuilder
        .path("/products/{id}")
        .build(2))
      .retrieve();
```

result: ***/products/2***

```
 this.webClient.get()
      .uri(uriBuilder - > uriBuilder
        .path("/products/{id}/attributes/{attributeId}")
        .build(2, 13))
      .retrieve();
```

result: **/products/2/attributes/13**

### URI Query Parameters

```
this.webClient.get()
  .uri(uriBuilder - > uriBuilder
    .path("/peoples/")
    .queryParam("name", "Charlei")
    .queryParam("job", "Plumber")
    .build())
  .retrieve();
```

result:

```
/peoples/?name=Charlei/job=Plumber
```