# Send Request Parameters in Spring Web client

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux

I want to send link Request Parameters in Spring WebClient request link. For example:

https://www.test.com/notification?con=41280440000097&sec=1232

I tried this code:

```
WebClient client;

Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();

public Mono<Response> execute(Transaction transaction) {

    map.put("some_key", "some_value");

    Mono<PaymentTransaction> transactionMono = Mono.just(transaction);

    return client.post().uri("/notification", token)
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
                .body(transactionMono, Transaction.class)
                .attributes(Consumer<map>)
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(Response.class);
}
```

But when I try to set the map I get Syntax error on token `">"`, Expression expected after this

What is the proper way to implement this without hardcoding the values into the address?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how-to-create-request-with-parameters-with-webflux-webclient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48828603/how-to-create-request-with-parameters-with-webflux-webclient)

Comment: Do you mean **Request Parameters** here? 
`queryParam("name", "spring-framework")`

Comment: Yes, wrong post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does this work?

```
public Mono<PaymentResponse> execute(PaymentTransaction transaction, WebClient client) {
        long conn = 1L;
        int sec = 1232;

        Mono<PaymentTransaction> transactionMono = Mono.just(transaction);
        return client.post()
                .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder.scheme("https").host("www.test.com")
                        .path("notification")
                        .queryParam("con", conn)
                        .queryParam("sec", sec)
                        .build())
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
                .body(transactionMono, PaymentTransaction.class)
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(PaymentResponse.class);
    }
```

Comment: Man, am I the only one who's really turned off by this new multi-tiered, deep-nesting syntax?

Answer (score 1):

This works for me

```
WebClient client;
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
public Mono<Response> execute(Transaction transaction) {

        Map<String,String> attributeMap = new HashMap<>();
    attributeMap.put("some_key", "some_value");

    Mono<PaymentTransaction> transactionMono = Mono.just(transaction);

    return client.post().uri("/notification", token)
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
                .body(transactionMono, Transaction.class)
                .attributes(map -> map.putAll(attributeMap))
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(Response.class);
}
```